# How to generate <img> with SVG in a v-for loop in Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Template:

```
  <div v-for="feature in features" :key="feature.label">
    <img :src="feature.icon">
    <div>
      {{ feature.label }}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Data:

```
features: {
  first: {
    icon: '~assets/svg/cards/first.svg',
    label: 'First label'
  },
  second: {
    icon: '~assets/svg/cards/second.svg',
    label: 'Second label'
  },
  third: {
    icon: '~assets/svg/cards/third.svg',
    label: 'Third label'
  },
  fourth: {
    icon: '~assets/svg/cards/fourth.svg',
    label: 'Fourth label'
  }
}
```

However I can't seem to find a way for this to work.

- `:src="feature.icon"` returns `http://localhost:3000/~assets/svg/cards/first.svg`
- installing `nuxt-svg-loader` adds `[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "src". Expected String with value "[object Module]", got Module` if you try to do the one above, in addition to the existing error
- `:src="require(feature.icon)"` returns `'Cannot find module '~assets/svg/cards/first.svg''`
- `x.icon: require('~assets/svg/cards/first.svg')` returns `'Cannot find module '~assets/svg/cards/first.svg''`

All the tutorials that I find online suggest the first method from the list above, but they all use `.png`/`.jpg` files

However, just `<img src="~assets/svg/cards/first.svg">` without any additional modules works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend that move your `.svg` files to `static` directory in root of your project so you don't have to worry about Webpack or any other config. your file will be available via `/name.prefix`

Change your data like below:

```
features: {
  first: {
    icon: '/svg/cards/first.svg',
    label: 'First label'
  },
  second: {
    icon: '/svg/cards/second.svg',
    label: 'Second label'
  },
  third: {
    icon: '/svg/cards/third.svg',
    label: 'Third label'
  },
  fourth: {
    icon: '/svg/cards/fourth.svg',
    label: 'Fourth label'
  }
}
```

And finally:

```
<img :src="feature.icon">
```

Reference: 
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets/

Answer (score 1):

In `Nuxt.js@2.15` version

You can use `require` to import images dynamically.

```
<img :src="require(`~/assets/img/${image}.jpg`)" />
```

Reference: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/assets#images